# Find whether the following tree exists in the list of million of binary search trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

For example,

consider the following tree's, check whether they exist in the list of BST.

```
           5
          / \
         4   6
        / \
       1   3


       3
      / \
     2   4
```

How to approach to this problem?

Comment: Step #1: Define what equality means in the context of binary search trees.

Comment: Two BST are equal if the data within every nodes & their left & right subtree are equal.

Comment: what is "the list"? What does it contan etc.

Comment: Go through the list and compare each node with the tree that you have? It's O(N) which I don't think is so bad for a naive approach like this

Comment: @ElKamina, the list consist of BST's. Specifically, it contains the reference to the root nodes of the BST's.

Comment: You could parse each tree and make a hash (precomputed), compare hashes... with a hash table, that is O(1)

Comment: Is the list sorted in some way? Any complexity requirement? The algorithm that @Calpis recommends, with minor variations, seems like a good solution anyway. I feel like some information is lacking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was put all the trees of the list in hash table so that there is constant time search for a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list according to the root (if roots are same then left node etc). For each query tree do a binary search.

This works if the number of queries is comparable to number of elements in the list. Complexity: ( (n+m)logn) where m is the number of queries and n is the number of elements in the list.

If the number of queries is small, brute-force searching is efficient.

Comment: This is O(N*log(N)), which is asymptotically worst than the natural scanning algorithm.

Comment: @naitoon What is a natural scanning algorithm?

Comment: Run along the list comparing the given tree with the current visited tree (I think this is what you call 'brute-force'). It's O(N) with a constant factor depending on the size of the tree you are searching for.

Comment: @naitoon Yes. But what if you have a large number of queries?

Comment: Yes, you're right, in that case you can amortize that cost. I was placing myself in the case where you are searching only a small number of trees. Your answer is more general. I think it answers the question better, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put it up as an answer so people can make variations if they'd like.

A naive approach would be to just scan through the list, compare each node and once you see a difference in the two trees you're comparing, just go on to the next one in the list. => O(N) where N is the total number of nodes.